# Output send by bash script on email is not preserving the desired format

Tags: bash, bin

I have a bash script to display a formatted df -h command of linux ,however when the same is send by the script on a email it loses the entire formatting and columns gets staggered ..

I assume it due to incompatibility of the output with HTML ,is a way around the problem..

```
#!/bin/bash
MOUNTPOINTS=`mount |grep -Ev 'proc|sysfs|tmpfs|devpts|nfs|vmware|gvfs|none'|cut -d ' ' -f 3`
printf '%17s %17s %17s %17s %17s\n' "Filesystem" "TotalSize" "SizeUtilized" "SizeAvailable" "Utili%">> consol.txt
for  i in `echo $MOUNTPOINTS`
     do
        LINES=`df -h $i|wc -l`
          if [ $LINES -eq 2 ]
              then
                   df -h $i|tail -n 1|awk '{printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %16s  %22s\n", $6, $2, $3, $4, $5}'>> consol.txt
              else
                          echo "OK" >> /dev/null 
          else    

                df -h $i|tail -n 1|awk '{printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %16s  %22s\n", $5, $1, $2, $3, $4}'>> consol.txt
fi 
done

cat consol.txt|mail -s "output" pragul.rajendran@mail.com
```

[root@ingura60 ~]# cat consol.txt

```
   Filesystem         TotalSize      SizeUtilized     SizeAvailable            Utili%
         /             48G             36G              9.9G                     79%
     /boot            487M             19M              443M                      5%
       /ai             44G            3.8G               38G                     10%
  /archive             49G            180M               46G                      1%
   /backup            387G            255G              113G                     70%
       /bi             44G             20G               22G                     48%
    /dataC             33G             28G              3.4G                     90%
    /dataO            8.7G            4.4G              3.9G                     54%
    /dataW             73G             36G               34G                     52%
     /home             49G             41G              5.2G                     89%
   /qadapp             49G             36G               11G                     78%
      /tmp             49G            342M               46G                      1%
 /workarea             49G             38G              8.1G                     83%
    /data1            185G             52G              125G                     30%
   /dataM1            293G            240G               39G                     87%
  /citipay             39G             32G              6.8G                     83%
      /mnt            110M               0              110M                      0%
   /citiin             39G             32G              6.8G                     83%
  /citipay             39G             32G              6.8G                     83%
     /cola             51G             25G               26G                     50%
```

[root@ingura60 ~]#

Comment: You are wrapping all this in an HTML message later and sending it, do I understand that correctly? Then wrap it in a `<pre></pre>` tag.

Comment: No I haven't use HTML wrap anywhere in the code .. A newbie to bash scripting ..It would be really helpful if you could elaborate the around for me ..

Comment: In a plain text email this shouldn't be a problem. Hm...I was suspecting tab characters (in which case pinping the whole thing through `| expand` in the end would have fixed things), but there don't seem to be any. How exactly are you sending this? Also, there appear to be things missing from your script. There's an `if` with two `else` branches, for example.

Comment: You might want to edit that comment to foo@bar.com or something before a spammer grabs your e-mail address from it. Anyway, that should be fine if the text in consol.txt is properly formatted and your e-mail client uses a monospaced font to display it. Can't say more than that, I'm afraid.

Comment: I am using an outlook email client to view the output ,how should I go about to get the output in a readable format then ..

Comment: You've got two separate issues here, and the way you're asking the question conflates them: One is how you generate `consul.txt`, and the other is the email for it. If the generation is fine (`cat consul.txt` looks just the way it should), you don't need to include any generation code in your question -- just include an example of the text file exactly as it's generated, and the one line that's used to email it. If `cat consul.txt` looks wrong, on the other hand, then you don't need to ask about the email process, since the issue is definitely in generation.

Comment: ...in either case -- the case where it's right, or the case where it's wrong -- you should be including content of `consul.txt` in your question.

Comment: There's a setting in outlook that controls this, but sadly (happily) I haven't had to use outlook for a couple of years, so I can't tell you what that setting is. I found once that indenting each line in the body by two spaces would force the message to be displayed as plain text.

Comment: I have just added the expected output as it seen in consol.txt file ..However when the same is send via mail command to outlook it gets staggered ..could you please let me know a way around to preserve the format (as in consol.txt file) when I receive the output on outlook inbox ..

Comment: The problem is with Outlook, not with your script.